# How To Auto-Download An MP3 Download From Amazon S3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I must be missing something crucial in the AWS SDK for PHP documentation, or elsewhere in my understanding: you can allegedly set the headers in your request to the S3 client, so my code looks something like this:

```
$result = $client->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $audiofilename,
    'ResponseContentType' => 'audio/mpeg',
    'ResponseContentDisposition' =>   'attachment;filename=x.mp3',
    'ResponseContentEncoding' => 'binary',
    'ResponseExpires' => '0',
    'ResponseCacheControl' => 'no-cache'
));
```

But I just end up with a document and not a downloading file, whatever I try to do with `$result`. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? (Actually it doesn't *seem* like my attempts to set the response headers are doing much, so maybe that's the problem...)

Comment: Does the client object have credentials, or are you sending an anonymous request?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - trying to add credentials. Most recently via making $client via S3Client::factory(['key'=>'xyz', 'secret'=>'abc']);